# How to store values of the index in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have an array that looks like this

```
Array ( [0] => test1 [1] => test4 [2] => test2 )
```

I got this value from my database using Codeigniter built-in function

And whenever I try to insert this value back in my database, it's inserting the **index** instead of the **value** itself

The error I'm getting is
[image]

As you can see, instead of storing test1, test4, test2 in the fields under username, it is storing the index which are 0, 1, 2.

How to fix this please?

References:
@MichaelK

[image]

TABLE:

Project Table
[image]

User Table
[image]

Project-User Table
[image]

**VIEW**

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <?php echo form_open('admin/add_recommended'); ?>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
    <label>Recommended Employees:</label>
    <?php echo form_error('skillsRequired'); ?>
    <?php
        foreach ($users as $row) {
            $user[] = $row->username;  
        }
        print_r($user);
        echo form_multiselect('user[]', $user, $user, array('class' => 'chosen-select', 'multiple style' => 'width:100%;'));
     ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel-footer">
    <?php echo form_submit(array('id' => 'success-btn', 'value' => 'Submit', 'class' => 'btn')); ?>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function add_recommended() {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('skillsRequired', 'Skills Required', 'min_length[1]|max_length[55]');

        $lid = $this->admin_model->getID();

        foreach ($lid as $id) {
            $last_id = $id['projectID'];
            $data['users'] = $this->admin_model->getUsers($last_id);
        }
        $this->load->view('admin/projects/rec-employee', $data);

        if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
            //$this->load->view('admin/projects/rec-employee');
        } else {
            $users = $this->input->post('user');
            print_r($users);

            foreach ($users as $user) {
                $data = array(
                    'projectID' => $last_id,
                    'username' => $user
                );

                $id = $this->admin_model->insert('projectemp', $data);
            }

            if ($id) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Success! New Project has been added.</div>');
                redirect('admin/add_recommended');
            }
        }
    }
```

**RENDERED VIEW**
[image]

Comment: You are using input from a POST request like `$this->input->post('user')`. Is this input supposed to be an array? What result do you get if you try `print_r($users)` or `var_dump($users)`?

Comment: can you show print_r $users array in your question ?

Comment: @MichaelK yes, cause I want multiple values to be saved in my database. given that example: projectID = 106, username = test1 || projectID = 106, username = test4. Something like that

Comment: @rahul_m print_r is Array ( [0] => test1 [1] => test4 [2] => test2 )

Comment: @MichaelK Array ( [0] => test1 [1] => test4 [2] => test2 )

Comment: Very strange then.. Do you really put print_r directly after `$users = $this->input->post('user')` to check this?? Do you use the variable `$user` anywhere above the foreach loop?

Comment: Your table have foreign key constraint on which id ? And does project id with 106 exists in project table ? once print your $data also

Comment: @MichaelK Check my edited for your reference, and also i didn't use $user anywhere.

Comment: @rahul_m table users has username(primary key) table projectemp has username(foreign key) and yes project id 106 exists.

Comment: and what is the type of username ? means int or varchar ?

Comment: I meant putting print_r() after the POST request `$users = $this->input->post('user');` ... not after the database call.

Comment: username should be varchar in your table check once, and user_id should be your primary and related foreign key and not username

Comment: @rahul_m varchar

Comment: @MichaelK how do i print it out? my post request is in controller.

Comment: Just put `print_r($users)` the line under `$users = $this->input->post('user');` It is the content from this request you are using to insert data into your table...

Comment: Just my two cents here, but would it be better to store the projectID and userID in the relation table instead of projectID and username ?

Comment: @B_CooperA i dont have userID, I only have username as my primary key

Comment: @MichaelK this is the result of post Array ( [0] => 0 )

Comment: Yes.. thats where the problem lies.. You should check how your client side code looks, when you want to post data from a HTML-form

Comment: @blackcat7 Yes, I'm aware of that and my comment didn't have anything to do with this error, just making a point that it would be better to use id as primary key for users instead of usernames.

Comment: @MichaelK any idea how to fix it? I've stuck for  a day with this problem :>

Comment: @B_CooperA oh okay, well if I add another column userid, it can have duplicate username, is it?

Comment: We need to see the client code, HTML, Javascript etc.. to help solving this. Its probably simple to solve, but the problem is not in your codeigniter code here.. but that the POST array coming from a HTML form(?) is empty...

Comment: @MichaelK i'm not using any javascript. however, the input post from html side is posted in the 3rd code display

Comment: You are using echo `form_multiselect(...` that prints out the users as HTML options with mutiple select allowed. You need to make sure you have a proper `<form action="your_controller_url" method="POST" >` with correct action url etc... and a submit button that triggers the POST... I don't see anything of this in your question.

Comment: @MichaelK added sir.

Comment: @blakcat7 when from submits where it goes ? (need controller function)

Comment: @AbdullaNilam updated the codes sir

Comment: ...and the rendered HTML result from your view?

Comment: @blakcat7 where is `skillsRequired` field in view ?? `$this->form_validation->set_rules('skillsRequired'`

Comment: and `form_multiselect` is wrong. Syntax should be `echo form_multiselect(name, options,selected ,extra );`

Comment: @AbdullaNilam the skillsRequired is just a form valdation in case users didn't put anything/ and my form_multiselect is right. name = users[] which is an array, my options are still users, and my selected are still coming from users, extra is adding style to it.

Comment: @MichaelK i added an image

Comment: ... I meant the source code. Not the whole thing. Preferably the `<select>`-tag an som of the `<options value="test1">test1</option>`-tags... to see if the are formatted right.. and the `<form>` tag...

Comment: The only problem is that for some reason the selected options in your form does not get submitted correctly to the method add_recommended() in your controller... If you fix this, then the rest of your code will probably work fine..

Comment: Back at it eh @blakcat7? ;) Michael is getting at the same ideas I was getting at yesterday. You need to see what your the form is posting to your controller. I'd try to comment out the `load->view()` call in your controller and add `print_r($user);die();` at the top of your foreach in the controller and see what data you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

why you use `$data['users']` in controller. Where $users contains index value. You try this

//CONTROLLER

```
$data = $this->admin_model->getUsers($last_id); //last id is the latest id.
```

//VIEW

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
   $user[] = $row->username;
}
```

Comment: didn't work sir. It gave me an error that $data is undefined

Comment: compact $data from controller before use it in view

Answer (score 0):

Boy these are too many comments for a small problem.

First of all @blakcat7, I hope you won't mind If I suggest a little change in your DB Schema. Use indexes and proper normalization it always helps. I have simulated your case on my machine.

[image: User table]

It is your user table, I have added an ID with in this table.

[image: Projects Table]

Its your project table, just changed some field names, you can use your own

[image: Project User table]

This is your table to create your join, Although you could have used user_id or posted_by field in projects table which could solve your problem too

Now Where i see it, you have users in your database table, you also have added projects but now you want to assign or associate that project with the user.

Make it simple just create a view where you can see both projects and users

[image: Assign User]

Rendered by the Controller function

```
public function assignProject()
{
    $data['projects']=$this->admin_model->getAll('projects');
    $data['users']=$this->admin_model->getAll('user');

    if($_POST)
    {
        $this->admin_model->assignUser($_POST);
        $data['success']='User Assigned';
        $this->load->view('assignProjects',$data);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('assignProjects',$data);
    }

}
```

The view rendered by following markup

```
<form action="" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Project</label>
            <select name="project" class="form-control">
                <?php for($i=0;$i<count($projects);$i++){?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $projects[$i]['id']?>"><?php echo $projects[$i]['title']?></option>
                <?php }?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Users</label>
            <select name="user" class="form-control">
                <?php for($i=0;$i<count($users);$i++){?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $users[$i]['id']?>"><?php echo $users[$i]['username']?></option>
                <?php }?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Assing User</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Just hit Assign User and the following function in the Model will save it in the project-user table

```
public function assignUser($data)
{
    $record=array(
        'user_id'=>$data['user'],
        'project_id'=>$data['project'],
    );
    $this->db->insert('user_projects',$record);
}
```

Remember, always use an Index (ID) field in your tables, would make your DB iteration life simpler

Comment: A good suggestion to normalize the database, but this solution does not support multiple select and update of multiple users in one POST request.

Answer (score 0):

OKAY EVERYONE, THANKS Y'ALL FOR YOUR HELP. IT REALLY MEANS SO MUCH TO ME. AFTER LIKE 2 DAYS OF STRUGGLE I FINALLY FIXED MY PROBLEM. ^_^

*Special thanks to Michael K for helping me point out the problem and Malik Mudassar for giving me the idea how to do it.*

**Controller**

```
 public function add_recommended() {

            $lid = $this->admin_model->getID();

            foreach ($lid as $id) {
                $last_id = $id['projectID'];
            }

            $data['users'] = $this->admin_model->getUsers($last_id);

            $this->load->view('admin/projects/rec-employee', $data);

            if ($_POST) {
                $users = $this->input->post('recommended');
                foreach ($users as $user):
                    $data = array(
                        'projectID' => $last_id,
                        'userID' => $user
                    );
                    $id = $this->admin_model->insertRecEmp($data);
                endforeach;

                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Success! New Project has been added.</div>');
                redirect('admin/add_project');
            }
}
```

**Model**

```
public function getUsers($id) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users_skills e');
    $this->db->join('projects_skills p', 'e.skillsID = p.skillsID');
    $this->db->join('users u', 'u.userID = e.userID');
    $this->db->where('p.projectID', $id);
    $this->db->group_by('e.userID');
    $this->db->order_by('e.percentage', 'desc');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $result[] = $row;
        }
        return $result;
    }
    return false;
}

public function getID() {
    $this->db->select_max('projectID');
    $this->db->from('projects');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();

    return $result;
}

public function insertRecEmp() {
    $this->db->insert('projects_users', $data);
    }
```

**View**

```
<form action="add_recommended" method="post">
<select name="recommended[]" class="chosen-select" multiple title='Select Skills' multiple style="width: 100%;">
      <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($users); $i++) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $users[$i]->userID ?>"><?php echo $users[$i]->username ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
</select>
</form>
```

I completely changed my database and my PHP function for multi select